# undeclared identifier 'FBAppCall' 'FBDialogs'

Tags: ios, xcode5, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm recently trying to update the Facebook SDK on our application. I had no worries following the steps fom the [Upgrade guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading/) by Facebook.

I was able to compile without issues.

However, when I quit XCode, reopen my project and try to recompile I get an error about '**FBAppCall**' (undeclared identifier). All others classes from the SDK are working except this one and '**FBDialogs**'.

I am able to solve those errors by deleting the Facebook framework and adding it again. But I must do it every time I quit XCode.

I've tried to check or uncheck "*Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)*" with no luck. Also tried older versions of Facebook SDK but it didn't changed anything.
Also tried to clear all the Facebook SDK references from the project.pbxproj before readding the frameworks, in vain.

Thank you for helping me with this annoying issue..

Note: Already did all the configuration Facebook SDK is requiring in the [Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

Since I was upgrading from an older Facebook SDK, I had to delete the older FacebookSDK.framework file from $(PROJECT_DIR)/Frameworks and then re-add it in XCode.

Answer (score 0):

did you add

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

in your AppDelegate.m file?

Comment: Yes, since all the other Facebook classes are working. Thanks for your help though.