# IOS error when I use Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have added FacebookSDK.framework into my project,

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

but I get this error: 
Use of undeclared identifier 'FBAppCall'

I am working about function LoginFB, please help me.

Comment: Have you checked [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037583/undeclared-identifier-fbappcall-fbdialogs?)

Comment: We need more code in order to help you. Where do you use the SDK's functions? Do you use the `FBAppCall ` anywhere in your code? edit: according to the comment above this that's an Xcode problem, try following that solution, if it doesn't work come back with more code.

Comment: I use FBAppCall into this methods:
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActive];
    
}

Answer (score 0):

Please check all below points -

1. Select Project and goto Build phase -> Link binary with Libraries and select FacebookSDK.framework
2. Goto your viewcontroller and import - #import  and #import

Please delete existing added FacebookSDK.framework before doing the above step.

Answer (score -1):

please use latest Facebook sdk.
  https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk
it will work fine with me.